# How to open config file of another application

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, configuration, config

I have an config file`(.exe)` present inside another folder in my application. When I run my application I want to open the file and then edit some changes inside `appsetting`. I am able to get the path of the `.exe` file using

```
string directory1 = 
System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString(); 
string directory2 = @"DualPort\SGPMService.UI.exe";
string path1 = Path.Combine(directory1, directory2);
```

Now I am unable to load the config file. I tried using `xmldocument` and `filestream` both.

```
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.Load(path1);
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path1, FileMode.Open);
```

What would be the correct way to load the file and edit the changes ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("xxx.exe");
        // get value
        var item1 = config.AppSettings.Settings["akey"].Value;
        // set value
        config.AppSettings.Settings["akey"].Value = value;
        config.Save();
```